# Laravel - Redirecting with a link from ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I need to redirect users with a link that I should get from an ajax request. What I need is basically just a route for a page:

```
Route::get('/access', 'SubpagesController@access');
```

And in that controller I should redirect users to a link that I am supposed to get from the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url ,
    data : { search: 'test' },
    dataType: 'json',

    success : function(json) {

      link = metaArray[0].value;
    }
  })
```

Since, this will only be a route to which the users will be able to come only if they write the url for it, so there won't be any links on the page for it, I am not able to send any data from the frontend to backend to work with it?
I have no idea how can I go about this issue?

Comment: Can't you just return the URL in the AJAX request, then `window.location.replace()` them to the new page? Is the generated URL different every time?

Comment: I was thinking of redirecting it somehow already in the controller, so that I can avoid making request on the frontend

Comment: Well, the controller can redirect with `return redirect('/specialurl/'.$usertoken);` etc.

Comment: The controller redirecting would cause your ajax request to go to the new url, not your page. You need to fetch the url and use javascript to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url ,
    data : { search: 'test' },
    dataType: 'json',

    success : function(json) {

        window.location = metaArray[0].value;
    }
})
```

Just redirect with javascript using window.location.